# Как сделать что бы telegram бот реагировал один раз на сообщение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Использую официальное Telegram Bot API

Проблема в том что при отправке запрос getUpdates я получаю данные о сообщении человека, message_id в json ответе меняется только когда сообщение отправляет человек, какие есть официальные методы что бы повторно не отправлять реакцию на сообщение "/start" ?

```
import requests


token = 'TOKEN'
url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}'

def check_last_message(txt):
    message = requests.get(url + '/getUpdates?offset=-1').json()

    if message['result'][0]['message']['text'] == txt:
        chat_id = message['result'][0]['message']['from']['id']
        message_id = message['result'][0]['message']['message_id']
        return chat_id, message_id
    else:
        return 0

def send_message(method, chat_id, text):
    send = requests.get(url + f'/{method}?chat_id={chat_id}&text={text}')
    print(send.json()['ok'])

def main():
    send_message('sendMessage', check_last_message('/start')[0], 'Привет')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: БД использовать...

Comment: @Qwertiy больше никак ? Может можно как то обновить список сообщений ? они вроде сами удаляются через 24 часа, но это долго.